# Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, server, tomcat6

I upgraded Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS. However, Tomcat 6 isn't working. There are specific things that I have to implement using Tomcat 6. Are there workarounds to get Tomcat 6 running on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! [Tomcat 6 has reached EOL.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-60-eol.html) You should not rely on outdated software, rather find a way to upgrade your code. If you have specific problems with upgrading your code, ask on [so] if you cannot find the answer online.

Comment: @Melebius As of now we don't have any policy regarding the topicality of EOL softwares from external sources. Related: [Do we stop *supporting* external software?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18710/816190)